# Grouping Similar Images with names in them

Tags: machine-learning, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have some hundreds of images which need to be grouped together. All the images have names in it along with colors. Is there an easiest way to group them based on the names inside along with the colors? Are there any packages available in Python or any algorithms with which this could be done?[image]

For Example the image above has "boy" in it. If I had another similar image with the same name in it.Then how can I group them together.

Comment: Do you need advice on how to recognize the text, identify the background color, or simply the steps to take after these features have been extracted?

Comment: I want to recognize text in the Image and if I have a similar kind of image to the above one, I would want to be able to group them together.

Comment: If they are all using the same font, then you can start by extracting each character (grab the black areas in the image, label them) and doing something similar to [this digit classification example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/exercises/plot_digits_classification_exercise.html).  This would give you the words.

Comment: There may also be a much easier way, if you do not need to recognize the text: simply extract the foreground using thresholding, and compare the images directly using Euclidean distance (assuming the text is centered the same way).

Comment: The text color,font and position is not similar in every case.Do you think I could group similar images together even when this is the case based on the text? Or are there any other ways of grouping similar images together?

Comment: I'm sorry--you need to update the question to explain all the parameters, otherwise this question is impossible to answer.  You cannot apply OCR (as suggested below) if you don't have consistent fonts.  What is your definition of "similar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is as clear as this you might not even need machine learning: just group all the items with the same name in a dictionary using the name as the key. If the text is still clear but you want to group conjugates of name **stem** or **lemmatize** them with **NLTK**. If the text is clear but you want to group semantically related words that are not mere conjugates use a **topic model** or **word2vec**, which gives you a vector space embedding of each word you can then use to perform a **similarity search**.

I've highlighted the key terms to help you help yourself. The technical term for your problem is called **clustering**.

Comment: What I want to know is how to read text in Images and group Images with similar text

Comment: If the text is always as clear as it is in this image just run it through `tesseract`, then cluster the text as outlined above.

Comment: Tesseract looks like an awesome solution. Thanks Emre!